# Cannot invoke 'functionName' with an argument list of type '([(nameOfClass)])' in Swift xcode 6.3.1

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

Im learning swift now and having the following problem
Please help..

I have 3 classes- 
TableViewController
BroadcastModel
BroadcastRequest
I get the following error (the line of error is marked with comment)
 Cannot invoke 'requestFinished' with an argument list of type '([(BroadcastModel)])'

```
import UIKit

public class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var broadcasts = [BroadcastModel]()
//MARK: ViewControllerLifecycle
override public func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    //maybe will use the 2d array for sections of broadcasts..
    BroadcastRequest().requestNewBroadcasts()

}

public func requestFinished(requestedBroadcasts: [BroadcastModel]) {
    self.broadcasts = requestedBroadcasts  \* HERE IS THE ERROR *\
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

public class BroadcastRequest {

func requestNewBroadcasts() {
    var broadcasts = [BroadcastModel]()
    .....
    .....
    broadcasts.append(broadcast)
    TableViewController.requestFinished(broadcasts)
}
}

public class BroadcastModel: NSObject, Printable {
let id: String
let broadcastURL: String
...
...
override public var description: String {
    return "ID: \(id), URL: \(broadcastURL) ....."
}

init(...) {
... 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using:

```
 TableViewController.requestFinished(broadcasts)
```

You should define the function as a class function:

```
class func requestFinished(requestedBroadcasts: [BroadcastModel]) {
    self.broadcasts = requestedBroadcasts  \* HERE IS THE ERROR *\
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Recommend you to figure out the difference between function and class function and difference between class itself and class instance

If you want to do something to a class instance, you must have the reference to it, instead of only having the class name.

Comment: tried that . i get now the following errors -                                                1)'TableViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'broadcasts'
2) Cannot invoke 'reloadData' with no arguments

Comment: @user2993422 it seems the logic of your code is not correct, If you do what i said, you cannot use self in class function

Comment: Forget about what i said before. I recommend you to remove `BroadcastRequest ` and `BroadcastModel ` and shift `requestNewBroadcasts ` function into class `TableViewController `

Comment: ill try now. but why to remove BroadcastModel?

Comment: it worked . without the removing of BroadcastModel. change the answer so i can mark it V

Comment: @user2993422 Since your request is very simple. BTW, i recommend you to figure out the difference between class itself and class instance